# R: Getting probabilities of customer buying top-N items from recommenderlab package

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am using user-based collaborative filtering from `recommenderlab` package in R to make recommendations of top-N items to a user. I am using binary user-item matrix as an input (created from purchasing history).

Is it possible to get probabilities that the customer will buy the item for each of the top-N items instead of just getting the top-N items?

`dB` is my user-item matrix and I am using next code:

```
r <- as(dB, "binaryRatingMatrix")
rTrain <- r[1:874, ]
rTest <- r[875, ]

rr <- Recommender(rTrain, method = "UBCF", 
                   parameter = list(method = "Jaccard", nn = 50))

rrP <- predict(rr, rTest, n = 500, type = "topNList")
predCF <- as(rrP, "list")
```

In `predict` method in `caret` package you just need to specify `type="prob"`, so I am looking for something similar in `recommenderlab` package. I tried putting `type="ratings"`, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Standard recommendation algorithms predict ratings (which are scores), but not purchase probabilities. The idea is that the item with the highest rating (score) is the most desirable item and thus likely next purchase (maybe has the highest purchase probability), but that does not give you a probability directly.

Comment: how does "topN" return the predictions ? I assume it is based on some sort of distance. Is that possible to get that number out ?! to figure out quantitatively how much is different between the first and the second recommendation, and different between the second and third recommendation ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf ?